# Open Attachment on Create of Child Record

Tags: administration, attachment, button-overrides

I have a requirement for a custom app I am building to open an attachment on the parent record in a new window on create of a child record.

I have parent object `Quality_Assessment__c` with child object `Chart_Review__c`. `Quality_Assessment__c` has a PDF attached to it in the Notes & Attachments section. When a user clicks to create a new `Chart_Review__c` record I need to have the PDF attachment on the `Quality_Assessment__c` record open in a new tab as well as the record create page for the `Chart_Review__c` record.
Looking for help in generating the needed javascript for a custom button to accomplish this.

The 'Quality_Assessment__c' record will have a PDF file attached to it prior to the user clicking the 'New Chart Review' button.

My use case is to have users open the 'Quality_Assessment__c' record and perform what we call a Chart Review. To perform the Chart Review the user would click on a custom button called 'New Chart Review' which would do two things.

1. create a new 'Chart_Review__c' record displaying the new record edit page
2. open the PDF attachment from the related 'Quality_Assessment__c' record.

Preferably on click of the button the new record page would open in existing tab and a new tab with the PDF would open simultaneously.

Comment: can you update this question with some more details. 1. is it SFDC app. 2. are you creating record using any api? 3. are you trying to achieve this using force.com visualforce page and apex class. because what you are asking is quite simple thing.

Comment: Hi Himanshu, yes this is a SFDC app. I am not using any APIs to do this, just two custom objects and most likely a custom button with some javascript to perform the action I need. Programming is not my forte, I am sure it is something simple, just not sure how to go about it.

Comment: @JTannerCannon I understand some what. but when user click on `Chart_Review__c ` new button **I need to have the PDF attachment on the Quality_Assessment__c record open in a new tab as well as the record create page for the Chart_Review__c record** what do you mean pls clarify?

Comment: @Ratan - The 'Quality_Assessment__c' record will have a PDF file attached to it prior to the user clicking the 'New Chart Review' button. My use case is to have users open the 'Quality_Assessment__c' record and perform what we call a Chart Review. To perform the Chart Review the user would click on a custom button called 'New Chart Review' which would do two things. 1 - create a new 'Chart_Review__c' record displaying the new record edit page 2 - open the PDF attachment from the related 'Quality_Assessment__c' record.

Comment: @JTannerCannon,  both action should should happen at a time. means  new record edit page  open in new tab and current tab open pdf file ?

Comment: @Ratan preferably on click of the button the new record page would open in existing tab and a new tab with the PDF would open simultaneously.

Comment: one request all the comment details add in your question. Give me few mints I will provide you a sample answer

Comment: @JTannerCannon ask another question.I can't ans here. This is closed

Comment: @Ratan - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/102680/open-attachment-on-create-of-child-record-2

Comment: You can't change the behavoir of standard features, to do this you'll either need to do some magic with custom links/buttons or go custom  page (visualforce). This may change with lighning components in the future.