# Open Attachment on Create of Child Record (2)

Tags: attachment

I have a requirement for a custom app I am building to open an attachment on the parent record in a new window on create of a child record.

I have parent object Quality_Assessment__c with child object Chart_Review__c. Quality_Assessment__c has a PDF attached to it in the Notes & Attachments section. When a user clicks to create a new Chart_Review__c record I need to have the PDF attachment on the Quality_Assessment__c record open in a new tab as well as the record create page for the Chart_Review__c record. Looking for help in generating the needed javascript for a custom button to accomplish this.

The 'Quality_Assessment__c' record will have a PDF file attached to it prior to the user clicking the 'New Chart Review' button.

My use case is to have users open the 'Quality_Assessment__c' record and perform what we call a Chart Review. To perform the Chart Review the user would click on a custom button called 'New Chart Review' which would do two things.

create a new 'Chart_Review__c' record displaying the new record edit page
open the PDF attachment from the related 'Quality_Assessment__c' record.
preferably on click of the button the new record page would open in existing tab and a new tab with the PDF would open simultaneously.

Comment: Simply asking the same question again verbatim without taking steps to make it a good question will get closed again and possibly get you banned. Please look through [How to Ask a Good Question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Thanks, I realize it is a duplicate. Was asked to do this based on comments from another member. Obviously I'm new to the community so forgive me for stirring the pot too much.  I'll check out the article as well for future reference.

Comment: Ah well you deleted that question so I can no longer reference that thread. Good to know.

Comment: I've undeleted the original question and am closing this one as a duplicate. Please always work on your initial question, you may always update it to improve the clearness or provide updates. When closed you can still ask for it to be reopend, which will be done if the question has become answerable by our standards.

Answer (score 1):

First create a javascript list view button on `Chart_Review__c`

**In my example I took Account and contact object**

Sample code...

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/35.0/connection.js")}

// query the record
var qr = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id FROM Attachment where ParentId='" + "{!Account.Id}" + "'");
var records = qr.getArray("records");

window.open('/003/e', "_parent");

window.open("https://c.ap1.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file="+records[0].Id , "_blank");
```

---

For your case

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/35.0/connection.js")}

// query the record
var qr = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id FROM Attachment where ParentId='" + "{!Quality_Assessment__c.Id}" + "'");
var records = qr.getArray("records");

window.open('/003/e', "_parent");

window.open("https://c.ap1.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file="+records[0].Id , "_blank");
```

replace `/003/e` with `Chart_Review__c` object prefix..

Good luck..time for a beautiful sleep

Answer (score 0):

Still learning to format responses so forgive me if it is not correct. Thanks to @Ratan for his help with this! I owe you a beer or 10.

Below is the final code used to solve for this requirement. I had to tweak the record edit page to point to the `Record Type Select` page and instead of it being a `list view` button on the `Chart_Review__c` object I made it a `Record Detail` button on the `Quality_Assessment__c` detail page.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/35.0/connection.js")} 

// query the record 

var qr = sforce.connection.query("SELECT Id FROM Attachment where ParentId='" + "{!Quality_Assessment__c.Id}" + "'"); 
var records = qr.getArray("records"); 

window.open('/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=01I230000000C4z&retURL=%2F{!Quality_Assessment__c.Id}&save_new_url=%2Fa1A%2Fe%3FCF00N23000000Glc5%3D{!Quality_Assessment__c.Name}%26CF00N23000000Glc5_lkid%3D{!Quality_Assessment__c.Id}%26retURL%3D%252F{!Quality_Assessment__c.Id}', "_parent"); 

window.open("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file="+records[0].Id , "_blank");
```

Comment: FYI I recommend using [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) any time you write javascript, especially if you are posting it to forums such as this one.

Comment: Cool . @j-tanner-cannon.